# MVC DataAnnotations - Require at least one field in a group to be filled

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

How can I use DataAnnotations to validate that at least one of these fields are filled in?

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set;}
    public string Zip { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it using DataAnnotations you will need to make a custom attribute because as far as I know there is no built in attribute that will handle this.

To get you started, when you start a new MVC project there is a class called "PropertiesMustMatchAttribute" that is applied at the class level. You could base it off that without much difficulty